# Home automation schematic check

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, kicad

I've just designed my first schematic to use as a standalone water tank monitor powered off 12 V.

Is there anything obviously wrong with it, or are there any suggestions?

The water sensor is 2 wire 0-180 ohm.

WeMos D1 mini: [schematic](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/_static/files/sch_d1_mini_v4.0.0.pdf)

[image]

Below is the pcb layout gnd is copper filled

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.StackExchange. How do you create the 3.3V rail?

Comment: @LiorBilia The +3.3V power supply is provided by the WeMos D1 mini board.

Comment: Correct, as the 3.3 is only powering two signal devices there is enough power to run through the wemos integrated regulator. In a future revision I may go for a ESP32 SMD module in which case I will need a separate LDO.

Comment: Noted the 4.7k resistor is supposed to be 470ohm that gives a max voltage of just under 1v at full

Comment: 12V to 5V through a 7805 will generate a bunch of heat.  You better do the thermal calculations, and add an appropriate heat-sink for the desired current (if it's even possible).  Why not find yourself a relay with a 12V coil, then perhaps you could use a low-power 7805L for the 5V to the uC?

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen the source 12v will be coming from a battery, so could be up to 14.6V I wasnt sure how the relay may handle the variation in voltage. Also considering the total draw will be less than 350ma across the relay and the wemos I thought the 7805 would be fine, as its rated up to 1.5a

Comment: Seems mad to have to use a buck converter to drive a single relay

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen if i used 12v relays could i trigger them using a tip120? or other npn transistor? that will run from 3.3v

Comment: Yes you can drive the coil of a 12 V relay with an NPN transistor (or N-channel mosfet) whose base (or gate) is controlled with a 3.3 V GPIO. Note: for the NPN you need a base resistor to make sure the NPN does not try to sink the GPIO right down near GND.

Comment: The power dissipation in the 7805 will be current * (Vin - Vout). You mentioned 350 mA and 14.6 V. This means that the dissipation could be up to 0.35 * (14.6 - 5) = 3.4 W. The 7805 cannot dissipate over 3 W for any great length of time, and eventually the whole board will get hot if you try to make it do that. If you read the datasheet carefully, you will see that there are limits other than the current limit. You have to abide by the most limiting limit applicable. In this case, power dissipation and maximum junction temperature.

Comment: On the PC layout, the track from the +12V connector to the relay common terminal is much too close to the relay NO terminal for my liking.  Also, several tracks between U1 pads are not centered in the spaces - may lead to shorts.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone I think I’m going to scrap the little modules or change them to 5v usb powered with a 5v relay, taken onboard re the traces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from the community I have decided to change

-LM7805 for a buck converter module [K7805 from Digikey](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/mornsun-america-llc/K7805M-1000R3/13168132)

-Rerouted traces that were running too close to adjacent pads

-Removed the snaking from TX RX as this is handled onboard

I have ordered the first batch of boards and am excited to get them assembled, thank you everyone for your input